# Efficient reading of values in a binary file

Tags: python

I have a lot of binary files containing output of a numerical model. They are flat binary files containing output as floating point numbers. The files correspond to a four-dimensional array sorted in t-z-y-x order with x varying fastest. The thing is that for given x,y and z I need the values for all t. The simple solution of simply reading everything into one large numpy array and taking `data[:,z,y,x]` works of course but is not very efficient (I need to read many files).

What I have come up with now is the following (assuming `start_index` and `volume_size` to represent the correct things):

```
data=array.array('f')
with file(my_filename,'rb') as infile:
    for hour in range(amount_of_steps):
        if hour==0:
            infile.seek(start_index*data.itemsize,0)
        else:
            infile.seek(data.itemsize*volume_size,1)
        data.fromfile(infile,1)
```

I don't have to bother about enddianness and portability (although the latter has of course some merits). The whole thing runs on Linux and it is highly unlikely it will ever run on something else. So the question is: Is there a way to do this with higher performance? This is done on many files. I tried parallelization but it does not really help. Getting new hardware is not an option and SSDs even less so because of the amount of data involved. Neither is changing the file-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options could involve

1. to use [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html).

   With this, you map a file into the memory area, making its contents accessible as if it were in RAM. The components are read in as soon as they are accessed/needed, probably in the normal page size of the OS (4 kiB).
2. to read the complete file into memory. This does essentially the same as mmap, but without help from the OS. OTOH, it can be done in one run instead of in 4 kiB steps.

If you have the data in RAM (in a file), you can use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) to emulate a file again and to feed the `array.fromfile()` with it.

Having had a second glance on it, you can omit the `StringIO` stuff and use `array.fromstring()` instead.

Using only one read (or some few) should normally be faster than repetitive `infile.seek()` and `data.fromfile(infile,1)` calls, especially if you read only one value per call. (Except maybe if your step size (`volume_size`) is sufficiently big - skipping about several hundreds to thousands of bytes - then it COULD be faster to do it your way...)

Comment: I haven't got the hang of mmap yet and do not exactly know what StringIO is for. Maybe you could elaborate a bit? Reading the whole file is slower in my experience. The files are not huge (something around 10MB) but I may have to work through thousands of them.

Comment: Edited my answer in order to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. The point is, I am skipping about half a megabyte with the infile.seek(), so yes, my step size is very large.

Comment: So you have about 20 `read()` calls, each reading a few bytes. In this case, forget what I wrote - your approach should be faster then.

Comment: Having tried it, it does not really matter with my approach having a slight edge. Which leads me to the assumption that I am doing more or less the best I can. Thanks for the explanation though, this was interesting.

Comment: Seems to me that opening and close each file (whether you're using `mmap` or not) in order to read one floating point value is probably the bottleneck -- so it might be useful to try opening and closing them all at once, even if there are many of them.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd take a look at [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#memory-mapped-file-arrays). I've used it in the past for a problem similar to yours, with good results.

Comment: Thanks. This does not appear to be faster but produces nicer code.